# Обработка строк средствами "php4" перед добавлением в базу "MySQL"

Tags: php, mysql

Какими функциями лучше обрабатывать строки перед добавлением в базу, а какими функциями лучше обрабатывать строки при выводе из базы данных... Прошу учесть то что версия **php4** установлена на сервере... и поэтому функции типа **htmlspecialchars_decode** - работать не будут...

Соответственно надо чтоб все символы корректно добавлялись и корректно выводились...

Comment: `htmlentities()`, `htmlspecialchars()`, выводить достаточно используя `nl2br()`

Comment: PHP5 вышел 8 лет назад. Серьезно подумайте — а не пришло ли время?

Завести новый сервер, или виртуалку или chroot на старом, поставить туда свежую систему, перенести старое барахло, и жить уже чуть больше как человек. Или продолжать лепить костыли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед вставкой — `mysql_real_escape_string`. После выборки — `htmlspecialchars`, или, лучше, шаблонизатором.

Т.е.:

- Введено: «`"Вася Пупкин" <vasya@example.org>`»
- В SQL идет: «`\"Вася Пупкин\" <vasya@example.org>`»
- Из БД выбирается: «`"Вася Пупкин" <vasya@example.org>`»
- В HTML выводим: «`&quot;Вася Пупкин&quot; &lt;vasya@example.org&gt;`»

Если «сырые» исходные данные *гарантированно* не нужны (даже поиск по ним не надо делать) — можно обрабатывать `htmlspecialchars` и перед вставкой.

И подумайте про обновление. Обычно, это получается не так тяжело, как кажется на первый взгляд. Если у разработки конец жизни не за горами, то стоимость времени, потраченного, на обновление и перенос на порядок дешевле потенциальных затрат на опыты по некромантии с доисторическими технологиями. (Ну или, надеюсь, Вам за это платят *достойно*.)